# What datastructure is effective for minimizing the cost of look ups in hash table buckets?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, time-complexity

Given a hash table with collisions, the generic hash table implementation will cause look ups within a bucket to run in O(n), assuming that a linkedlist is used.

If we switch the linked list for a binary search tree, we go down to O(log n). Is this the best we can do, or is there a better data structure for this use case?

Using hash tables for the buckets themselves would bring the look up time to O(1), but that would require clever revisions of the hash function.

Answer (score 1):

There is trade-off between insertion time to look-up time in your solution. (Keep bucket sorted)

If you want to keep every bucket sorted, you will get O(log n) look-up time using Binary search. However when you insert a new element, you will have to place him in the right location so the bucket will continue be sorted - O(log n) search time for placing new element.

So in your solution, you get total complexity O(log n) for both insertion and look-up.
(In contrast to the traditional solution that take O(n) for look-up in the worst case, and O(1) for insertion)

**EDIT :**

If you choose to use a sorted bucket, of course you can't use LinkedList any more. You can switch to any other suitable data structure.

Comment: Insertion would be worse than O(log n) -- you can't use a linked list for binary search (as there is no random access), so you have to move up to n items one slot to the right even if your array is over-allocated.

Comment: Exactly, and in general one can't insert in an array in O(1) -- only at the end (or beginning, I suppose), if it's over-allocating. Inserting anywhere else means copying O(n) unrelated items.

Answer (score 1):

[Perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hashing) is known to achieve collision-free O(1) hashing of a limited set of keys known at the time the hash function is constructed. [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hashing) mensions several aproaches to apply those ideas to a dynamic set of keys, like [dynamic perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) and [cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), which might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own question. Since a hash table is just an array of other data structures, your lookup time is just dependent on the lookup time of the secondary data structure and how well your hash function distributes items across the buckets.

Comment: What would be the preferred secondary data structure?

Comment: Use a balanced binary search tree or a second hash table.